Validating a variable's character length within batch script
I am checking whether a variable string value, (with this format YYYYMMDD), has a total length of eight characters. However, even when I type exactly 8, it gives an error.
rem Get date for the new filenames
:enter_date_videos
set /p "date=Enter the date (YYYYMMDD) for the new filenames: "
if "!date!"=="exit" goto :EOF
if NOT "!date:~0,8!"=="!date!" or NOT "!date:~8!"=="" (
    echo Error: The date needs to be exactly 8 characters in the format YYYYMMDD.
    goto enter_date_videos
)

I tried to do the !date:~0,8! so it checks if it is shorter then 8, and !date:~8! to check is it is equal to 8, but still no luck.

Change the variable name, date, to something other than an already existing built-in dynamic environment variable! A dynamic variable is updated every time it is used.

echo %variable%|findstr /x "[12][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][01][0123456789][0123][0123456789]" || ( echo Error ... & goto :enter_date_videos ) does check for exactly 8 digits and at least a bit of format checking (not fool-proof (29991939 would be considered sufficient), but a start)

There is no or option for the if command.  That should have been plain as day in the error message: 'or' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I suggest using:
rem Get date for the new file names.
:enter_date_videos
set /P "FileNameDate=Enter the date (YYYYMMDD) for the new file names: " || goto enter_date_videos
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo(!FileNameDate!| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X "[12][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][01][0123456789][0123][0123456789]" 1>nul & endlocal
if errorlevel 1 goto enter_date_videos

Run set /? in a command prompt and read the entire output help. There is the dynamic variable DATE which should be never become inaccessible by the definition of an environment variable DATE. See Difference between Dynamic Environment Variables and Normal Environment Variables in CMD for more information about dynamic and environment variables.
Next read: How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input? The code || goto enter_date_videos on the line with set /P results in prompting the user immediately again on entering nothing at all.
There should be read also the DosTips forum topic ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/ because of explaining the usage of ( instead of a space between echo and !FileNameDate! for output of the user input string with redirection to FINDSTR.
It is important having no space character after !FileNameDate! and | as that space would be output by ECHO too. That trailing space would result in regular expression find never matching a number string with exactly eight characters with first digit of the century being either 1 or 2, first digit of month being either 0 or 1 and first digit of day in month being either 0, 1, 2 or 3 and all other digits being in range 0 to 9. There are of course still invalid dates possible by that simple regular expression date string validation. Do not use [0-9] as FINDSTR would accept in this case also ¹²³ as valid digits which is definitely not wanted here.
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file explains the unconditional command operator & used on fourth line for temporarily enabling delayed variable expansion which is important here too. For the reason see: How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?
Read this answer for details about the commands SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL.
Why it is okay running always ENDLOCAL after FINDSTR and then checking the exit code of FINDSTR with if errorlevel 1 is explained by:

Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?
What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

echo /?
endlocal /?
findstr /?
goto /?
if /?
rem /?
set /?
setlocal /?


I made the code work by doing the following and using some of you guys tips.
:enter_date_photos rem Get date for the new filenames set /p "date=Enter the date (YYYYMMDD) for the new filenames: " echo !date! | findstr /R "^.........$" >nul if errorlevel 1 (
echo Error: The date must be exactly 8 characters in the format YYYYMMDD.
goto enter_date_photos )   

this checks if the answer given is really 8 characters not longer or shorter. Thanks a lot for the tips & tricks! :)
